# Merging two different XML log files (trace and messages) using date and timestamp?

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, timestamp, logfiles

I need to merge two XML log files. One log file contains a trace with position updates. The other log file contains the received messages. There can be multiple received messages without having a position update inbetween.

Both logs have timestamps:

- The trace log uses <date> (eg. 14.7.2012 11:08:07)
- The message log uses a unix timestamp <timeStamp> (eg. 1342264087)

The structure of the trace looks like:

```xml
<item>
        <date>14.7.2012 11:08:07.222</date>
        <MyPosition>
        // Position data
        </MyPosition>
</item>
<item>
        <date>14.7.2012 12:13:07.112</date>
        <MyPosition>
        // Position data
        </MyPosition>
</item>
...
```

The structure of the messages is like that:

```xml
<Message>
    // some content of the message
    <subTag>
        <timeStamp>1342264087</timeStamp>
    </subTag>
    // other content of the message
</Message>
<Message>
    // same as above
</Message>
...
```

When doing the merging, the timestamps should be read (also converting/comparing "date" and "timestamp") and all positions and messages added in the right order.

The position data can just be added as it is. However, the message should be placed inside of <item> tags, a <date> tag should be added (based on the messages' unix time) and the <Message> tag should be replaced by <m:Message type="received"> tags.

Unfortunately not a "simple" merging, especially as the size of the log files lays between 5 MB and 700 MB... :-/

A result could look like this:

```xml
<item>
        <date>14.7.2012 11:08:07.222</date>
        <MyPosition>
        // Position data
        </MyPosition>
</item>
<item>
        <date>14.7.2012 11:09:10.867</date>
        <m:Message type="received">
        // content of the <Message>
        </m:Message>
</item>
<item>
        <date>14.7.2012 12:10:11.447</date>
        <m:Message type="received">
        // content of the former <Message>
        </m:Message>
</item>
<item>
        <date>14.7.2012 12:13:07.112</date>
        <MyPosition>
        // Position data
        </MyPosition>
</item>
<item>
        <date>14.7.2012 12:17:11.227</date>
        <m:Message type="received">
        // content of the former <Message>
        </m:Message>
</item>
...
```

Are there any tools which support a merging like that? Or is there any simple way to solve this using java?

I really appreciate any tips on how to solve this matter.

Comment: I would convert them to an excel table or a database table.  Then you could sort by date/time

Comment: This sounds like a job for an XSL tranform, preferably using XSLT2 since it's better at handling multiple input streams.  I've re-tagged your post to include XSLT.  My XSLT is a little rusty, but maybe one of the XSLT gurus on SO will see it and help out.

Comment: I think the major problem is the comparison of unix timestamps and dates and the adding of a date-tag containing a converted timestamp... is this also possible with xslt? My knowledge in this topic is quite limited.

Comment: Yes, this is all possible with XSLT, but if you don't know XSLT at all the task could be daunting without some help.  If you changed your tags back I suggest you at least add XSLT. Tags `timestamp` and `logfiles` are marginal at best -- what you have is an XML Merge task that would be the same for ANY two XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation** (for convenience containing the small message-log sample inline):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:m="some:M" exclude-result-prefixes="xs m">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDateU0" select="xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMessages">
    <Message>     // some content of the message
        <subTag>
            <timeStamp>1342264087</timeStamp>
        </subTag>     // other content of the message
    </Message>
    <Message>     // some content of the message2
        <subTag>
            <timeStamp>1342264089</timeStamp>
        </subTag>     // other content of the message2
    </Message>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="vProcessedMessages">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vMessages/*"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vProcessedTrace">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
  </xsl:variable>


  <xsl:perform-sort select="$vProcessedMessages/*|$vProcessedTrace/*">
    <xsl:sort select="xs:dateTime(date)"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Message">
  <xsl:variable name="vUnixDuration" select=
   "concat('PT', */timeStamp, 'S')"/>
  <item>
   <date><xsl:sequence select=
    "$vDateU0 + xs:dayTimeDuration($vUnixDuration)"/>
   </date>
   <m:Message type="received">
     <xsl:sequence select="text()[1]"/>
   </m:Message>
  </item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="date/text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vdatePart" select="substring-before(., ' ')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vYear" select=
  "substring-after(substring-after($vdatePart, '.'), '.')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vMonth" select=
  "substring-before(substring-after($vdatePart, '.'), '.')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vDay" select="substring-before(., '.')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vFormattedMonth" select=
  "if(string-length($vMonth) eq 1)
    then concat('0', $vMonth)
    else $vMonth
    "/>

  <xsl:variable name="vFormattedDay" select=
  "if(string-length($vDay) eq 1)
    then concat('0', $vDay)
    else $vDay
    "/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat($vYear,
          '-',
          $vFormattedMonth,
          '-',
          $vFormattedDay,
          'T',
          substring-after(., ' ')
          )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when performed on the provided Trace-log XML document**:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <date>14.7.2012 11:08:07.222</date>
        <MyPosition>         // Position data         </MyPosition>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>14.7.2012 12:13:07.112</date>
        <MyPosition>         // Position data         </MyPosition>
    </item>
</items>
```

**merges the two logs as required**:

```
<item>
   <date>2012-07-14T11:08:07</date>
   <m:Message xmlns:m="some:M" type="received">     // some content of the message
        </m:Message>
</item>
<item>
        <date>2012-07-14T11:08:07.222</date>
        <MyPosition>         // Position data         </MyPosition>
    </item>
<item>
   <date>2012-07-14T11:08:09</date>
   <m:Message xmlns:m="some:M" type="received">     // some content of the message2
        </m:Message>
</item>
<item>
        <date>2012-07-14T12:13:07.112</date>
        <MyPosition>         // Position data         </MyPosition>
</item>
```

**Note**: In the real case the Message-log will be obtained using the `document()` function.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at XSLT and report back as soon as I've tried it out! :-) As I've never worked with XSLT before: Any tips on good websites with tutorials?

Comment: If you were more advanced in your XSLT knowledge I would suggest using XSLT 3.0 which has an xsl:merge instruction that's absolutely a 100% fit to your requirement; but that's really bleeding edge (early draft spec) so I would steer clear. Dimitre's code as always does the job fine. As for tutorials, my preference before using a new language is to buy a book and spend a day reading it, and of course I would recommend my own!

Comment: @SebastianMauthofer: See this answer for some recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/36305. When I first got into XSLT, I baught Michael Kay's book and studied it for a month. This is what it takes for a serious XSLT education.

Comment: I've got a problem while using Saxon:
    Error on line 39 of transform.xsl:
      FORG0001: Invalid duration value 'PS' (non-numeric component)
      at xsl:apply-templates (file:transform.xsl#20)
         processing /Messages/Message[1]

...as it seems, this error is caused by this line:
    <xsl:variable name="vUnixDuration" select="concat('PT', */originator/originatorPosition/timeStamp, 'S')"/>

I changed the "PT" to "P", but the error remains...

Comment: @SebastianMauthofer: You need to test your code -- obviously this error means that what is selected by your XPath expression `*/originator/originatorPosition/timeStamp` isn't a number, like the value of the `timestamp` elements in the XML that you originally provided. Either the XPath expression is wrong or the XML document has other structure and value types than the one you showed to us.

Comment: As Saxon gave me some XML-Errors i had to add "<itemList>" as the root for the items and "<Messages>" as the root for the messages in the xml-logs. The structure given above is slightly simplified: The Timestamps are within a deeper level (Messages/Message/originator/originatorPosition/timeStamp) and the unix-timestamp contains additional milliseconds as the last three digits (but for testing I removed them and will try to handle them later). Beside that there are also some elements inbetween that are neither messages nor items and can be ignored... :-/

Comment: @SebastianMauthofer:Then, please either edit your question and provide a more representative XML document, or, recommended, ask a new question, this time better.

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct one and created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180499/xslt-merging-two-log-files-with-different-structure-and-time-representation

I hope it's ok like that... :-)