# How to merge multiple xml files with different node structure into a single xml file in java or any other tool?

Tags: java, xml

I have many xml files with different node structure and different nodes. Now I want to merge these two xml files in a single xml file. after searching , I found that i can use xslt for merging multiple xml files and every example is dealing with xml files having same nodal structure.

Thanks Stephen for your suggestions but i am facing different scenario. Following are the snippet of xml files which i want to merge together and also the final xml file should look like.

file1.xml

```
<Equipment>
<Items>
   <Item>
     <ID>_stdpart_38100</ID>
     <Index>1</Index>
     <SubcategoryIDRef>Power</SubcategoryIDRef>
  </Item>
 </Items>
 <Subcategories>
  <Subcategory>
    <ID>Power</ID>
    <CategoryIDRef>Power and Handling</CategoryIDRef>
  </Subcategory>
  <Categories>
  <Category>
  <ID>Power and Handling</ID>
  <Title>Power and Handling</Title>
  <Subtitle />
  </Category>
 <Categories>
 </Equipment>
```

file2.xml

```
<Models>
 <Model>
 <ID>S Sedan</ID>
<Name>S Sedan</Name>
<Index>1</Index>
<Equipment>
  <Item>
    <IDRef>_stdpart_38100</IDRef>
    <Optionality>S</Optionality>
  </Item>
<Equipment>
</Model>
</Models>
```

and the final merged file should look like
merged.xml

```
<Models>
 <Model>
    <ID>S Sedan</ID>
    <Name>S Sedan</Name>
    <Index>1</Index>
    <Equipment>
    <Item>
        <ID>_stdpart_38100</ID>
       <Index>1</Index>
       <Subcategory>
         <ID>Power</ID>
         <Category>
            <ID>Power and Handling</ID>
            <Title>Power and Handling</Title>
           <Subtitle />
         </Category>
     </Subcategory>
     <Optionality>S</Optionality>
   </Item>
   </Equipment>
  </Model>
</Models>
```

Comment: does your DTD support the varying node structures?

Answer (score 1):

> I found that i can use xslt for merging multiple xml files and every example is dealing with xml files having same nodal structure.

Here is an example in which the XML files have radically different structure:

- [XSLT: Merging two log files with different structure and time-representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180499/xslt-merging-two-log-files-with-different-structure-and-time-representation)

<sub>If this doesn't help, update your question with examples of your XML and what you need the merged file to look like.</sub>

Comment: Hey Stephen, I have updated my question...i request you to go through and suggest solution to the same

Comment: @abhijeet - I'm sorry, but that amounts to me doing your job for you.  That is not what SO is about.

Comment: I got your point...I am just struggling with the comparison on nodes in two different xml files... if i can get some example on it...i can do it